# How to set websocket session parmateters using autobahn in python

Tags: python, websocket

I am using autobahn library for websocket connection in python to nodejs server. I have to change header and origin parameters of the connection but its giving me error that

```
factory.setSessionParameters(url="wss://xyz.com",origin='54:53:ed:29:23:85',protocols=['ovrc-protocol'],useragent=None,headers={'name':'ravi'})
TypeError: setSessionParameters() got an unexpected keyword argument 'headers'
```

I even tried to save the values in keywords and pass those keywords as arguments to the setSessionfatory method

```
url= "wss://xyz.com:1443"
headers = { 'Sec-WebSocket-Key':'uRovscZjNol/umbTt5uKmw==' }
origin='50:50:ed:27:21:33' 
protocols=['wxyz-protocol']
useragent=None

factory.setProtocolOptions(version=13,utf8validateIncoming=False)
factory.setSessionParameters(url,origin,protocols,useragent,headers)
```

But then it return with error saying method setSessionParameters accepts 5 argument, 6 arguments provided

clearly there are only 5 arguments . i was following this link for the method 
http://autobahn.ws/python/websocketclient.html
it has details for setSessionParameters and its an actual doc but its not working at all.

If possible please suggest me easier way to do websocket connection in python where i can change websocket parameters like origin and sec-WebSocket-key value etc.

Thanks

Comment: This works as advertised, there is even an example: https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/tree/master/examples/twisted/websocket/echo_httpheaders - Probably you are running an old Autobahn?

Comment: Thanks oberstet as i installed autobahn for apt-get it did install an old version. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I ran into another issue the connections is getting closed prematurely saying message received connection was closed uncleanly (None) ..

Comment: Is your server accepting the subprotocol you announce? Also: the `origin` you provide above (`54:53:ed:29:23:85`) is invalid. This needs to be a valid HTTP(S) URL (see here https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6454). Maybe the server checks that.

Comment: Its actually a device mac address and as i am running the client from a local machine. do i need to include the ip of the remote machine in origin?

Comment: I get the ping on server side but before server can send a response, client closes the server with message in onclose event message received connection was closed uncleanly (None)

Comment: My client is a raspberry pi device and trying to connect to a cloud service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry it was a silly mistake apt-get installed an old version of autobahn . I have installed the binary provided by autobahn site and problem solved :)